# How to access nonce value created during build process

Tags: reactjs

I'm referring to this [article](https://medium.com/@nrshahri/csp-cra-324dd83fe5ff) to create content security policy. By flipping the the existing calls to react-scripts in npm scripts and Adding config-overrides.js file in the root directory, I'm able to dynamically create nonce value

My config.overrid.js file looks like this

```
const {override} = require('customize-cra');
const cspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require("csp-html-webpack-plugin");

const cspConfigPolicy = {
    'img-src':    [" 'self' blob: https://api.company.com/  data:"], 
    'script-src': ["'self' https://abc.stripe.com js.stripe.com  https://billing.stripe.com https://www.googletagmanager.com"  ],
    'connect-src':[" * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com https://billing.stripe.com"],
    'frame-src':  ["'self'  https://checkout.stripe.com  https://billing.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com ;"],
};

function addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin(config) {
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        config.plugins.push(new cspHtmlWebpackPlugin(cspConfigPolicy));
    }

    return config;

}

module.exports = {
    webpack: override(addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin),
};
```

Dynamically created nonce value during build time

```
<meta http-equiv="Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-DpAw3sfasvaX12pPA==' 'nonce-Hf+DsdsdP324242d7ySSSDSDA=='".
```

For nonce-aware version of GTM snippet, I need to pass nonce value to GTM snippet like this. Read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp)

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script nonce='{SERVER-GENERATED-NONCE}'>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;var n=d.querySelector('[nonce]');
n&&j.setAttribute('nonce',n.nonce||n.getAttribute('nonce'));f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager --
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to get this nonce value in index.html so that I can pass it to the GTM Snippet.

Comment: Hello. Have you been able to resolve this issue? I'm currently trying to do the same thing in a React application and I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: I was not able to fix this